# как ускорить функию dist()

Tags: r

есть вектор "х" и матрица "у"

нужно максимально быстро посчитать евклидову дистанцию между  "х" и каждой строчкой матрицы "у"

штатную функцию "dist()" обогнал , написав свою

```
штатная

system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {dist.ve[i] <- dist(rbind(x,m[i,]))})

   user  system elapsed 
   4.38    0.00    4.39

самописная

system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {dist.ve[i] <- euc.dist(x,m[i,])})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.65    0.00    0.67
```

но  этого мало, хотелось бы ускорить до второго нуля 0,0....

что еще такого можно придумать?
код:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
m <- matrix(data = rnorm(1000000),ncol = 10)

euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))

dist.ve <- rep(0,nrow(m)) # distance vector
system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {dist.ve[i] <- dist(rbind(x,m[i,]))})
system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {dist.ve[i] <- euc.dist(x,m[i,])})
```

Comment: Rcpp можно использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ускорить ваш вариант можно скомпилировав функцию в байт-код.

Также можно переписать код на C++. В данном случае вполне хватит sugar-функций `Rcpp`.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector euc_dist3(const NumericVector& x, const NumericMatrix& y) {
    size_t n = y.nrow();
    if (x.size() != y.ncol())
        stop("Length 'x' and ncol 'y' must be equal.");
    NumericVector res = no_init(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        res[i] = sqrt(sum(pow(x - y.row(i), 2.0)));
    return res;
}
```

Эквивалентный код без использования синтаксического «сахара»:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector euc_dist3(const NumericVector& x, const NumericMatrix& y) {
    size_t n = y.nrow(), m = y.ncol();
    if (x.size() != m)
        stop("Length 'x' and ncol 'y' must be equal.");
    NumericVector res = no_init(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double tmp = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            tmp += std::pow(x[j] - y[i + n * j], 2.0);
        res[i] = std::sqrt(tmp);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Код для сравнения производительности:

```r
# Данные для сравнения
x <- rnorm(100)
m <- matrix(data = rnorm(1000000), ncol = 100)

euc_dist <- function(x, m) {
    res <- numeric(nrow(m))
    for(i in 1:nrow(m))
        res[i] <- dist(rbind(x ,m[i,]))
    res
}

euc_dist2 <- function(x, m) {
    res <- numeric(nrow(m))
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(m)))
        res[i] <- sqrt(sum((x - m[i, ]) ^ 2))
    res
}

all.equal2 <- function(...) {
    l <- list(...)
    all(sapply(l[-1], all.equal, l[[1]]))
}

# Комплируем функции в байт-код
library(compiler)
euc_dist_c <- cmpfun(euc_dist)
euc_dist2_c <- cmpfun(euc_dist2)

# Убедимся, что функции возвращают одинаковый результат
all.equal2(euc_dist(x, m),
           euc_dist_c(x, m),
           euc_dist2_c(x, m),
           euc_dist2(x, m),
           euc_dist3(x, m))

# Сравниваем производительность функций
library(benchr)
benchmark(euc_dist(x, m),
          euc_dist_c(x, m),
          euc_dist2_c(x, m),
          euc_dist2(x, m),
          euc_dist3(x, m))
```

Результаты сравнения:

```
R> # Убедимся, что функции возвращают одинаковый результат
R> all.equal2(euc_dist(x, m),
..            euc_dist_c(x, m),
..            euc_dist2_c(x,  .... [TRUNCATED] 
[1] TRUE

R> # Сравниваем производительность функций
R> library(benchr)

R> benchmark(euc_dist(x, m),
..           euc_dist_c(x, m),
..           euc_dist2_c(x, m),
..           euc_dist2(x, m),
..           euc_dist3(x, m) .... [TRUNCATED] 
Benchmark summary:
Time units : milliseconds 
             expr n.eval   min  lw.qu median   mean  up.qu    max total relative
   euc_dist(x, m)    100 187.0 191.00 193.00 195.00 194.00 244.00 19500    99.70
 euc_dist_c(x, m)    100 180.0 183.00 184.00 186.00 185.00 237.00 18600    95.10
euc_dist2_c(x, m)    100  15.9  16.50  16.70  17.80  19.80  23.00  1780     8.65
  euc_dist2(x, m)    100  24.9  25.80  28.70  27.90  29.40  31.00  2790    14.80
  euc_dist3(x, m)    100   1.6   1.89   1.93   1.91   1.97   2.09   191     1.00
```

Как видим, скомпилированный вариант `euc_dist2` (`euc_dist2_c`) показывает себя весьма достойно, при том, что используется только нативный R-код.

Если очень сильно надо ещё ускорить, то можно переписать с использованием `RcppParallel`.

Comment: Спасибо! Это лучший ответ из всех возможных!!!

Comment: Еще одна просьба, я не владею с++,  подскажите как  эту функцию (euc_dist3) запустить прямо из R кода?  в том виде что вы показали она выдает ошибки, библиотеку Rccp запустил

Comment: Самые основы использования Rcpp, проще не бывает: https://bookdown.org/csgillespie/efficientR/performance.html#rcpp

Comment: У меня какие то проблемы с RTools , из за этого и ошибки, сейчас решаю все это дело.......     А книжка очень занятная , спасибо , буду читать однозначно

Comment: @mr.T, сохраняете верхний кусок кода в файл и запускаете `Rcpp::sourceCpp("/path/to/file.cpp")`. После этого можно пользоваться функцией `euc_dist3` как обычной R функцией.

Comment: Спасибо все заработало! у меня просто RTools не работал коректно